# Consume message from jms queue

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, apache-camel

How consume messages that put on "jmsQueueConsumer:queue:consumer.queue" in following code:

```
CamelContext context1 = new DefaultCamelContext();
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory1 = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory2 = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
        context1.addComponent("jmsQueueProducer", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory1));
        context1.addComponent("jmsQueueConsumer", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory2));
        context1.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("jmsQueueProducer:queue:producer.queue").to("jmsQueueConsumer:queue:consumer.queue");
            }
        });

        ProducerTemplate template = context1.createProducerTemplate();
        context1.start();


        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            template.sendBody("jmsQueueProducer:queue:producer.queue", "Test Message: " + i);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could configure another route to process it. eg:

```
from("jmsQueueConsumer:queue:consumer.queue")
.process(new Processor() {
               @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                  // your processing code here
                }
            })
   .to(any other endpoint)
```

Also, you can extract your processor as a separate class by itself.

Comment: For congigure another rout, i need another camelContext?

Comment: No, everything should be in the same camel context. you just have to add this line before context1.start().                                           context1.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("jmsQueueConsumer:queue:consumer.queue").to("any other endpoint");
            }
        });